# Worklfow 4: Cannot load XAML Activity that uses another XAML Activities from compiled assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I work with **MS Workflow** technology.
I'm trying to create reusable `State Machine` component that can be usable in another activities.
In screenshot in Workflow Toolbox you can see in category `User flow` my custom `Activity` Trees. Inside of "*Prerequesite Tests*" Activty Tree the Sequence with Code Activities.
[image]
[image]
Each compiled activity - it's the **XAML** file that compiled as embed resource in `dll`. Per each XAML - it own dll:
[image]

New assembly for each type needs because I didn't find the way how to update existed dynamic dll when it was loaded to domain. Reloading existed domain or creation of new one was not helpful.
This is the code I used to compile the dll from **XAML** file:

```
 public static string Compile(string xamlPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var schemaContext = new XamlSchemaContext();

            object xamlLoadedObject;
            using (var xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(xamlPath, new XamlXmlReaderSettings { LocalAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(VirtualizedContainerService)) }))
            {
                var builderReader = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(xamlReader, schemaContext);
                xamlLoadedObject = XamlServices.Load(builderReader);
                builderReader.Close();
            }

            var activityBuilder = (ActivityBuilder)xamlLoadedObject;

            //for each xaml - create it's own assembly
            string ns = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xamlPath);
            var fileName = ns + ".dll";

            var typename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xamlPath);

            // Set up the assembly builder based on namespace of activity

            var ab =
              AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                  new AssemblyName(ns) { Version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0) },
                  AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);


            var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(fileName, fileName);

            // Part 1: define the class
            var newClass = BuildType(mb, activityBuilder, typename, false);
            var createdType = newClass.CreateType();


            using (var stringStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(xamlPath)))
            {
                // Part 2: embed the XAML as a manifest
                var xamlResourceName = createdType.FullName + ".xaml";

                mb.DefineManifestResource(xamlResourceName, stringStream, ResourceAttributes.Public);

                // TODO create a common working envitonment for the tool
                // End: save the generated assembly                    

                ab.Save(fileName);
                return fileName;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.ToString();
        }
    }
```

After that I load all of types to make it avialable for usage from Workflow Designer:

```
 private void LoadUserFlows(ToolboxCategoryItems categories)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.WorkflowFolder))//for the first time
            FlowPath(null);

        var userFlowsCategory = new ToolboxCategory(ConstUserFlowsCategorynName);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Settings.Default.WorkflowFolder, "*.dll");

        foreach (var type in files.SelectMany(file => Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Activity).IsAssignableFrom(t))))
            userFlowsCategory.Add(new ToolboxItemWrapper(type, type.Name));

        categories.Add(userFlowsCategory);
    }
```

It's available in Workflow Toolbox for reusing in another Activities.
For now it works fine, but it fails in second part of my task: 
The Main Tree XAML file (that uses compiled sub-trees - Lab_CompiledComponents.xaml) should be also compiled as embed resource to release DLL (UserActivities.dll). I need to make possible loading of the Main Tree from release dll (UserActivities.dll) without Lab_CompiledComponents.xaml  usage. 
Software should provide load Activity by Activity name from DLL:

```
  private StateMachine LoadActivityByName(string typeName)
    {
        Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\UserFlows\Release\UserActivities.dll");
        Type t = assem.GetType(typeName);

        Stream resourceStream = t.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(t.FullName + ".xaml");



        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(resourceStream))
        using (var reader = new XamlXmlReader(xmlReader, new XamlXmlReaderSettings
        {
            LocalAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\UserFlows\Release\UserActivities.dll")
        }))
        {
            using (var xamlReader = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(reader))
            {
                var xaml = (ActivityBuilder)XamlServices.Load(xamlReader);
                return xaml.Implementation as StateMachine;
            }
        }
    }
    private StateMachineNode LoadStateMachine(string path)
    {
        var smFromString = LoadActivityByName("Lab_CompiledComponents");
        return LoadStateMachine(smFromString);
    }
```

I got exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:;assembly=Prerequisite_Tests}Prerequisite_Tests'.
>   [image]

I understand the nature of this issue: my Main Tree holds xmlns reference to unknown assemblies.
[image]
I try to load this Main Tree from DLL from the code that doesn't know Prerequisite_Tests.dll (and another Sub Trees holder) and it shouldn't.
When I tried to hack and change the assembly names directly in XAML to release DLL name (UserActivities.dll):
[image]
I get the exception during atempt to create release DLL (UserActivities.dll):

> 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:;assembly=UserActivities}Prerequisite_Tests'.' Line number '59' and line position '20'.

So now I succeed to load tree that uses another compiled trees only if I have available both: compiled dll (UserActivities.dll) to load all of required sub tree components, and the Main Tree (Lab_CompiledComponents.xaml) with changed all sub tree xmlns definitions to "UserActivities" in the file. I must to use both, but I need to make available loading by using only DLL.

Sorry for long description, but by my opinion the problem is complexly, and I want to explain it as good as I can.
The question is how to "push" XAML with invalid namespace to DLL? 
Or maybe how to "drag out" XAML from dll when environment doesn't know about components that uses inside of this xaml?
Does somebody know another way to resolve this issue or it is impossible?

Thanks in advance for any help!